# Django queryset to a string

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset by doing:

```
chart_data = DetailChange.objects.extra(select={'day': 'date(captured_date)'})\
    .values('item_id__store_id__store_name', 'day')\
    .annotate(total_sale=Sum('amount_sold'))
```

then I have a queryset like this:

```
{'day': datetime.date(2019, 6, 24), 'item_id__store_id__store_name': 'Keyboard Pro', 'total_sale': 706.0}
{'day': datetime.date(2019, 6, 25), 'item_id__store_id__store_name': 'Keyboard Pro', 'total_sale': 18.0}
...
```

now what I want to do is get one single string that combines all the days in it, separated by ",". Like:

```
"2019-6-24, 2019-6-25, 2019-6-26, ..."
```

Is there an easy way to get it done?

Comment: Why do you return `item_id__store_id__store_name` and annotate it if thats all you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the an iterable of formated date strings, like:

```
', '.join(item['day'].strftime('%Y-%-m-%-d') for item in chart_data)
```

So here we thus will format each `day` object, like:

```
>>> dd.strftime('%Y-%-m-%-d')
'2019-6-24'
```

and we then join these together, separated by a comma and a space (`', '`).

That being said, if you are only interested in formatting the date, it makes not much sense to first add extra annotations.

Comment: @Ken: what version do you use? Works fine on 3.6.

Comment: It worked.  just took the "-" out between '%-m-%-d'.  thanks.

Comment: @Ken: but then it will format it like `2019-06-24`, the dash has specific purpose: to remove the leading zero.

Comment: it was strftime('%Y-%-m-%-d') it didn't work.  I changed it to strftime('%Y-%m-%d') then worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with genexp and `str.join` with `,` as the separator:

```
', '.join(str(item['day']) for item in chart_data)
```

`str(datetime.date)` i.e. `datetime.date.__str__` already returns the date in `%Y-%m-%d` format so you don't need to do any additional `strftime` work.

OTOH, if you only need the `day` field, you should not include `item_id__store_id__store_name` in `values`.

Comment: @Ken If you want the `0` in months to be omitted you need to use the `strftime` format specifier `%Y-%-m-%-d` (a leading `-` before `m`) (as shown by @Willem).